# PHP Session inconsistent on different computers?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a PHP program that uses session variables to pass data over several PHP scripts.  When I test it on my normal computer it flows just fine, and the session data holds through where expected, gets maintained on page refreshes, etc.

The strange thing I'm encountering is that on a *secondary* computer, the session is wildly inconsistent.  I'll arrive at a page and it acts as if none of the session variables had been set.  What's even stranger is, if I try reloading the page, *sometimes* the variables will actually load (and if I refresh again, they disappear again).

From what I can tell the problem doesn't seem to be browser-specific (I've tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE on both computers), but rather computer-specific, which seems really strange to me.  I asked two other people to try it out, and discovered the exact same issue -- for one person the program runs just fine, but for the other person the session variables load inconsistently.

Any thoughts?  I'm not doing anything fancy with the session, I just have the session_start() calls at the beginning of the scripts, post data via forms, and access/store via $_SESSION.

**Edit**:  Some additional details --- in firebug, on the computer that isn't affected I'm seeing 3 cookies, which I guess I should be expecting (I'm admittedly not much experienced in session management and cookies).  On the computer that is affected though, I'm not seeing any cookies at all in Firebug, even when the page does randomly load properly.

Also for clarification, I do expect the session data to be distinct for each computer, I'm **not** expecting data from one computer's session to be available on another computer's session.

**Edit 2**:  I checked the cookies in firebug again, and it does seem like the 3 cookies are showing up on the affected computers (maybe it wasn't loading properly earlier today).  I've done a var_dump of the $_SESSION variable on the pages that aren't displaying the data correctly, and sure enough all the information is there.  It's just, for some reason it only sometimes loads in the HTML section below.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: It depends on your version of PHP. Make sure you use `isset()`. Please show code.

Comment: Could you show some code or the link where to test it? Does error log show something?

Comment: Are you expecting that the session state you arrived at on the first computer somehow persists when you visit the page on the second computer?

Comment: I'm currently using PHP 5.3.17.  On what should I be using isset()?  Why would that effect the program on different computers?

Comment: Also tell some details on the server setup, have a look at the HTTP requests (Firebug, F12 - requests tab) - does your browser send the cookie with the session id, when you miss values?

Comment: I'm expecting the session state to be completely different on the different computers.  Some computers hold their sessions just fine, but other computers are randomly losing all their session data at once (or rather maybe not losing it, just not having access to it sometimes when the page loads).

Comment: I unfortunately can't show a sample since it's for work, and I also don't have access priveleges to the error log. :\

Comment: It seems on the computers experiencing the problem, there's no cookies at all.  On the computers that aren't affected, though, I'm showing 3 cookies, which I guess is what I should be expecting.

Comment: Whether or not to allow cookies is on a browser-by-browser basis. If you need cookies to function, and the computer's owner has decided to be paranoid and ban cookies, you're out of luck. Could that be what you're seeing? I would imagine there is code to test whether cookies are usable on a given machine.

Comment: The weird thing is, I own both of the computers, the one that's working and the one that isn't, and the cookie settings I'm pretty sure are the same on both of them, which is part of why I'm so confused that this issue is happening in the first place.  Not just that, but the data does load intermittently in the wonky computer if I keep refreshing (which compounds the weirdness).

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of digging around and testing, I finally figured it out, and the answer was surprisingly obscure and yet under my nose at the same time.  My company uses VPN to tunnel remote desktops to our work servers.  Although the pages I had set up on the work servers were accessible and worked properly via the browser (which is what threw me off), the session cookies weren't passing properly to the affected computers because those computers didn't have the site's IP address mapped to the work domain in their Windows hosts files.  Once I mapped the IP address to the site domain, everything worked perfectly like my primary computer.  Thanks to everyone who gave the issue some thought!